# Google Places iOS: How to provide context to API for relevant local results

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

Using [Google Places API for iOS](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/), I am using the [Place AutoComplete feature](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete). When I start typing a place name for example 'Starbucks' it gives me starbucks location in several countries but not my local starbucks. How do I pass the current location to the API so the search results start from closest to my location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a `GMSCoordinateBounds` to the which is *"object biasing the results to a specific area specified by latitude and longitude bounds"*.

They have an example on their [site](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete) showing how to do this:

```
let visibleRegion = self.mapView.projection.visibleRegion()
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: visibleRegion.farLeft, coordinate: visibleRegion.nearRight)
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.type = GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter.City
placesClient.autocompleteQuery("Sydney Oper", bounds: bounds, filter: filter, callback: { (results, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    guard error == nil else {
        print("Autocomplete error \(error)")
        return
    }

    for result in results! {
        print("Result \(result.attributedFullText) with placeID \(result.placeID)")
    }
})
```

This example show how to pull this data from a map view but you can also create the `GMSCoordinateBounds` manually.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice. But I do not want to limit the results to any area. I just want it to give me results closest my current location first.

Comment: It doesn't seem like that is a feature of the Places API. If you need this functionality though I'd recommend making 2 separate place requests. One that you'd pass your current location to and one that has no location restriction. Then you can sort the list based on the distance from your current location.